# How to collect all inputs from one input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with multiple questions. Each question requires an answer and I want to collect all the answers. Below is an example:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6zyovcp/)

The reason why I use one `input` field for multiple questions is that, all my questions are in the same format (i.e., given an image, requiring some answers), and I want to make sure the location of `input`, `next` and `submit` button stable. So I reuse the `input` field.

However, when the form is submitted, it turns out that if I have only one `<input>` field (i.e. the one with id `grade`), only the answer of last question will be recorded.

One potential solution is to create one `<input>` field for each question. However, since the number of questions vary a lot (can range from 3 to any number), I don't want to create the `input` fields in one by one. Also, I will need to use the `form` to do this.

Is there a way to collect the inputs of all questions? I prefer to use one `input` field, but I'm open to add multiple fields as well, as long as the fields can be dynamically created and added, and the fields and buttons are in the same location all the time.

---

Edit:

I follow the suggestion of putting all answers in array and submit the array in the end. However, while the `output` field does carry all answers, it doesn't seem to submit successfully. What is wrong with the updated code? [updated jsfiddle with inputs in array](https://jsfiddle.net/trom1a67/)

Comment: is it possible for you to push the value of the input into the array of answers and then when on clicks the submit button submit the  array of answers wherever it is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I edited my code for the array and submit. However it doesn't seem work. I edited my OP with the new code I have.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove the form tag it is reloading the page.
Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!--<p>image ${image_url}</p>-->
          <img src="" class="img-fluid" id="image" height="auto" width="700" align="center">
      </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <label>Please grade with anything:</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input id = "grade" type="text" max-length="25" value="" required></input>

</fieldset>


<p><input type='submit' id='next' value='Next' style="display: inline"/></p>

<p><input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' style="display: none"/></p>


<script>



var imageIndex = 0;

var images = [
                    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/June_odd-eyed-cat.jpg",
                    "https://www.aaha.org/contentassets/f557d057200b4d7197d67acce3ea725f/image9iii.png",
                    "https://cdn3-www.cattime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/persian-cats-and-kittens/persian-cat-breed-pictures-1.jpg"    
                ];

var output = []

function next()
{   
    //document.getElementById('grade').value = '';

    var grade = $("#grade").val();

    output.push(grade);


    if (grade != '') {
      imageIndex = (imageIndex+1) % (images.length);    
      $("#image").attr('src', images[imageIndex]);


      // set to empty
      $('#grade').val(""); 
      //$('#grade').val(output.length); 

    }


    if(imageIndex == images.length - 1) {
        $("#next").attr('style', 'display: none');
      $("#submit").attr('style', 'display: inline');
    }

}

function submit()
{   
    var grade = $("#grade").val();

    output.push(grade);
    docWrite(output); // verify that the output variable stores all inputs.
    console.log(output);
    // output.submit();

}

function docWrite(variable) {
    document.write(variable);
}


    $( document ).ready(function() {
                $("#image").attr('src', images[0]);

        $("#next").on("click", next);

        $("#submit").on("click", submit);

    });
</script>



<!-- <h3>the value for number1 is: <script>docWrite(output)</script></h3> -->



</body>

</html>
```